# SVN via Tomcat and WebDAV

Tags: svn, tomcat, webdav

I'm trying to configure WebDAV for accessing SVN via Tomcat **without** using Apache Webserver.

-> without using the Apache Webserver due to the fact the existing Tomcat is providing Websites on Port 80 + 443
-> With SVN due to the fact it is our well-established Versioning System and there is no way for a discussion to change

By now I already configured a Tomcat host for the WebDAV-Delivery and I need to 'bind' the SVN-Repo to the WebDAV.

Does somebody can provide some hints for the configuration?

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [scm-manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just set up SVN to run as a service and use the `svn:` protocol.  Just an idea.

Comment: Not mentioned the problem behind - okay: I need to have an authorization via LDAP and have to deliver the repository at port 443. Just setting up the SVN is of course an proper idea, but in my circumstances I have to do it the hard way.